# Split mysql data into 3 bootstrap md columns with php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to divide some info retrieved from a mysql db to 3 columns ("col-md-4") without repeating the info. I have been have trouble with mysqli_fecth_assoc() beacuse it replicates the info in all columns. Any idea? Thanks in advance

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <?php while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
        <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
        <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
        <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

the problem with thath code is that it repeats the same $fila["Nombre"] in all columns.

Comment: Can you show your code, please? That'll be easier.

Comment: not too much code to add, but thats what i got

Comment: Why are you printing this  $fila["Nombre"] thrice? Since this is within a loop, for a single row you will get the same name thrice.

Comment: I want to print $fila["Nombre"] in all the columns but not the same one. I know the code doesnt work. If I have 5 diferent $fila["Nombre"]`s i want them all to display in 3 columns but not repeat.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow is not for most of the assignment questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help to get the expected result.

```
<?php 
    $tempFila = array();

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
        $tempFila[] = $fila["Nombre"];
    } 

    $count = count($tempFila);
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $count;) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p><?php echo (!empty($tempFila[$i])) ? $tempFila[$i] : ''; $i++; ?></p>
            <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p><?php echo (!empty($tempFila[$i])) ? $tempFila[$i] : ''; $i++; ?></p>
            <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p><?php echo (!empty($tempFila[$i])) ? $tempFila[$i] : ''; $i++; ?></p>
            <HR WIDTH="50%" SIZE="3"> 
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a possibility to be generated at most 2 unnecessary column. That problem can be fixed using the column into the conditional block.

Comment: that works, thanks, what about if im trying to display more than 1 column, for example, i want to display "nombre" and "apellido"

Comment: There are several ways to do that. 
1. Use another array for "apellido"

2. Use a two dimensional array like this

    $tempFila[0]['nombre'] = $fila["Nombre"];
    $tempFila[0]['apellido'] = $fila["apellido"];

    $tempFila[1]['nombre'] = $fila["Nombre"];
    $tempFila[1]['apellido'] = $fila["apellido"];

    and so on..........

Comment: I think is not efficient to do 8 arrays just to save 8 different info.

Comment: Yes. So you can choose the second way.

See this:

$tempFila = array();
$i = 0;

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
        $tempFila[$i]["Nombre"] = $fila["Nombre"];
        $tempFila[$i]["apellido"] = $fila["apellido"];

       $i++;
    }